# Where to get exact version of internet explorer 9.0.8112.16421CO

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

and what does it mean "CO" in the name? 
I have a website failing to display correctly (css file problem). Client has Win 7 Enterprise Edition SP1 with that ie version. 
I do tests on browser stack which has ie 9.0.8112.16421 (without CO). It could be the problem - different browser versions. And I cannot replay the error because client is forbidden to use "remote desktop" app.

Comment: Dealing with something similar myself, I can tell you that the "CO" indicates that it is the enterprise edition configured for a corporate policy.  There is a registry key that goes with this which will specify a `SiteList` string value, dictating an `.xml` file to use to determine what version of IE to emulate for particular urls.  You can read more about it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969393).